# How to return the highest value for every different row parameter

Tags: sql

I'm trying to become the MAX value of a set of rows, on every year that is displayed.
I can see what I have to do, I just can't seem to translate it into code.

```
select YEAR(O.Orderdate) [Year] , SUM(O.Freight) [Total Freight], S.CompanyName
from Orders O inner join Shippers S on S.ShipperID = O.ShipVia
group by S.CompanyName, YEAR(O.Orderdate)
```

1996    4233,78

1996    2297,42

1996    3748,67

1997    11413,35

1997    8681,38

1997    12374,04

1998    4865,38

1998    5206,53

1998    12122,14

The code returns the total freight for each company (although company name not displayed), per year. I then need to get the highest amount of freight, for every year.

I used following code, but it returns the highest value for all years, and although I know it's wrong, I cannot see the logic or a way to return the highest value for every year separately...

```
select YEAR(O.Orderdate) [Year] , SUM(O.Freight) [Total Freight]
from Orders O inner join Shippers S on S.ShipperID = O.ShipVia
group by S.CompanyName, YEAR(O.Orderdate)
having SUM(O.Freight) >= ALL (
                                select SUM(O.Freight)
                                from Orders O join Shippers S on S.ShipperID = O.ShipVia
                                group by YEAR(O.Orderdate), S.CompanyName
                            )
```

This returns:

1997    12374,04

While my goal would be:

1996    4233,78

1997    12374,04

1998    12122,14

I don't need a blatant solution, I'd really much rather have the logic in what I'm doing wrong/what I should be doing.
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is checking for sum of freight values being greater than equal to all values, so only the maximum value from year 1997 is matched , so only one row is returned

if you want maximum per year, i would go with @Gordon answer, but as per comment, you want to do it using Group by and having.

here is another way by having your current query in subquery.

```
SELECT Year, Max(TotalFreight) as [Total Freight]
FROM (
select YEAR(O.Orderdate) [Year] , SUM(O.Freight) [TotalFreight]
from Orders O inner join Shippers S on S.ShipperID = O.ShipVia
group by S.CompanyName, YEAR(O.Orderdate) T
group by Year
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Because your code was incomplete, I had to wrap my mind around your solution, resulting in actually understanding what is written, instead of just copying the code, and your solution is exactly what I needed for the exercise !

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using window functions:

```
select [year], [Total Freight]
from (select YEAR(O.Orderdate) as [Year] , SUM(O.Freight) as [Total Freight],
             row_number() over (partition by year(o.orderdate) order by SUM(o.freight) desc) as seqnum
      from Orders O inner join
           Shippers S
           on S.ShipperID = O.ShipVia
      group by S.CompanyName, YEAR(O.Orderdate)
     ) yf
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Works like a charm, but half of the code is stuff we haven't handled yet. The exercise is mainly about group by and having... Thanks though, I'll keep the code handy for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [MAX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187751.aspx) operator

```
select orderyear, MAX(freight)
from (values(1996, 4233.78),(1996,2297.42),(1996,3748.67),(1997,11413.35),(1997,8681.38),(1997,12374.04),(1998,4865.38),(1998,5206.53),(1998,12122.14)) as Q(orderyear, freight)
group by orderyear
order by orderyear
```

And why you you join to the Shippers table, if you don't need any information from it its kinda useless...?

Comment: Thanks for the addition. The reason why it is joined is because I need the CompanyName from that table, although it isn't listed in the select clause I posted. I'll edit accordingly so it makes sense.